# What parts do I need to replace for my bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, upgrades, upgrade-or-new-bike

I have a MTB ([2000  Giant  XtC SE2](http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2000&brand=Giant&model=XtC+SE2)) with a frame size of 17.5 that I haven't used for 10 years, I was a 5 ft 6 inch and 130lbs back then.

I'm planning to use it again , I'm currently at 6 ft 1 inch and weigh 200lbs.

Which is more practical? Upgrading some parts of bike or getting a new one?

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the bike?   You've grown taller and heavier, and the bike's frame is a bit small for you?   Its probably worth passing on to someone else and buy yourself one that fits better.

Comment: i've read some articles that getting a layback seatpost ,getting a longer stem might and having a wider handlebar might help

Comment: Any standard adult bike can handle a guy weighting 200 pounds.  But likely the bike is a bit small for you now.  You can swap out the handlebar stem (and possibly the seatpost) and gain a little bit of effective size, but in the long run you probably want a larger bikes.  But ride what you have for awhile, to understand better what features you'd like.  It's really discouraging to lay out the bucks for a new bike and then realize it's not what you should have bought.

Comment: You're going to have to get a different bike. You may want to rent a few or something to see what you like now and for what kind of riding you do.

Comment: Longer seatposts would help, but there's a point where you have a hundred kilos on the end of a long unsupported lever.  Personally I have bent multiple seatposts in my adult life, doing exactly this.  Not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the bike has been kept dry in the intervening years then lube it up, possibly replace the tyres and you're good to go.  However I suspect the problem is your increased height, and to a lesser extent, weight. For your weight, the only things to consider are tyre pressure and maybe stiffening up the forks a little if that is possible.

However, to get the bike to suit your height will be tricky, a 17.5" frame is pretty small for a 6'1" person.  I'm 5'10" and my Specialized of the same size and era feels small after riding properly sized modern era bikes.  You'll probably require an extended seat tube and maybe a longer stem.  The cranks are likely to be 175mm anyway, so you'll have limited choices for anything longer.  But I think it'll end up being less than ideal, the highly extended seat post in particular being a weakness.

I think if you were to try a modern bike for size you'd find the long frame / short stem geometry and 27.5" wheels to your liking.  You're going to need to go to a bike shop to get the seat post and any other bits anyway, so there's no harm in trying.  If you don't like the feel of the new bikes, do up your old one so it kinda fits.  Otherwise shine it up and make back some money to help fund your new purchase.